# Method annotated with @Bean is called directly. Use dependency injection instead

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I'm following a tutorial for Spring Batch and when I write the following code - IntelliJ is complaining that the tasklet(null) call in the job function is called directly:

```
Method annotated with @Bean is called directly. Use dependency injection instead.
```

I can get the error to go away if I remove the @Bean annotation from the job - but I want to know what's going on. How can I inject the bean there? Simply writing `tasklet(Tasklet tasklet(null))` gives the same error.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name) {
    return ((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("This is %s", name));
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    });
}

@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .tasklet(tasklet(null))               // tasklet(null) = problem
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

asd

Comment: @Configuration on class helps in Spring Boot

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name) {
    return ((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("This is %s", name));
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    });
}

@Bean
public Job job(Tasklet tasklet) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .tasklet(tasklet)
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

Spring Bean creation and AOPs are very picky. You need to be very careful with the usage.

In this case you can use bean dependency to solve the TaskLet name being null.

Comment: Thanks. However I'm struggling to understand what's going on. As I said I could also get rid of the problem by removing the @Bean annotation from the job. How is the AOPs picky in this case, and what if I wanted to pass an argument to the bean?

Comment: AOP is not in place here, here in place is bean creation.  IIUC Value annotation is not in action here since you're calling that method  from the same class.